# How to use wildcard in PDO multi-word query?

Tags: search, pdo, wildcard

The project I am working on requires a multi-word search... just as an example search 'Sprint Apple iPhone'. If any one of these words matches a column in my database, the contents of the entire row must be displayed.

I *believe* I have got this secured from SQL injection now, but may be wrong. The main issue I am trying to solve now is that I can only search for one word at a time, for example, 'Sprint' or 'Apple' or 'iPhone' but if I put in the entire query no results are displayed.

Partial queries do work for example 'Sprin' or 'Ap' or 'iPho' ... not sure where I am going wrong. I have looked at several examples on StackOverflow that work for a single word query but can not find a multiple word solution.

Any help is appreciated!

```
<font size="+3" face="Verdana">xxxx</font>
<br><br>
<form name="form" action="xxxx.php" method="get">
<input type="text" name="q" size="60" />
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Search">
</form>

<table>

<?

$var = $_GET['q'];

try {
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxxx', $username, $password);
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM phones WHERE carrier LIKE :search OR        
manufacturer LIKE :search OR model LIKE :search");
$stmt->execute(array('search' => "%$var%"));

$result = $stmt->fetchAll();

if ( count($result) ) {
foreach($result as $row) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" .$row['carrier']. "</td>";
echo "<td>" .$row['manufacturer']. "</td>";
echo "<td>" .$row['model']. "</td>";
echo "</tr>";    
}
} 
else {
echo "No results found.";
}
} 
catch(PDOException $e) {
echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: I assuming all those xxxx are not the same, please se ome real field names.  Also :search isn't used for each Like is it?

Comment: I updated the fields to make it a bit more readable. :search is used for each LIKE because the query is from the same search box for all 3 columns.

Answer (score 1):

Consider how a multi-word keyword will look once the query is build:

```
SELECT ... WHERE somefield LIKE '%apple iphone%'
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You can't simply dump a bunch of words into a `LIKE` block and expect it to work. At best, you have to do some massaging:

```
... WHERE somefield LIKE '%apple%' AND somefield LIKE '%iphone%'
                           ^^^^^                        ^^^^^^
```

but this gets VERY ugly VERY VERY FAST for any "long" query string.

To make it easier, you simply switch to a [fulltext index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//fulltext-boolean.html):

```
... WHERE somefield MATCH(somefield) AGAINST ('apple iphone')
```

Comment: Thanks. I got the 2nd method to work but it is bringing up irrelevant results as well... for example if I put in Sprint Apple, it brings up iPhones for other carriers and also any other Sprint phone.

That was part of the reason I was using LIKE, the results are much more exact, but maybe there is a way to improve the results on this method? The other problem is ft_min_word_ln or whatever, it does not allow 2 letter searches like 'LG'.

I have also tried the first method but no matter where I put the % signs it will only work with a single word.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem myself, it wasn't actually a solution by using code, but by automatically combining Carrier, Manufacturer, and Model together in to 1 column in my database when they are originally inserted in to the database, then matching that 1 column against the search query provided by the user.

Comment: When the phone is inserted in to my database I just made it add the whole name, for example 'Sprint Apple iPhone' in to the fullphonename column, then just search against that 1 column.

New Code:
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM Phones WHERE fullphonename LIKE :search");